# How to copy the blob from the Azure storage to linux virtual machine using python?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

I am new to Azure cloud services as i am not getting how to copy my blob from the Azure storage account to Linux virtual machine(vm) using python.
In my application,i am storing the uploaded file to Azure storage and i have also triggered the Azure function whenever the new file get uploaded now i need to copy that file to Azure VM from Azure function.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a code snippet specifically for Python Azure Functions. It reads a file from Blob Storage into memory and then transfers it to a remote location using SSH (specifically SFTP over SSH). It uses a library called `paramiko` for SSH.

```
import logging
import paramiko

import azure.functions as func


def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh_client.connect(hostname='YOUR_HOST_NAME', username='USERNAME_FROM_APP_SETTINGS', password='PASSWORD_FROM_APP_SETTINGS')

    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
    with open('LOCAL_FILE_LOCATION', 'wb') as f: 
        f.write(myblob.read()) 

    ftp_client=ssh_client.open_sftp()
    ftp_client.put('LOCAL_FILE_LOCATION','REMOTE_FILE_LOCATION') # same file location written to above
    ftp_client.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your time,this is exactly what i am looking for.It successfully copy my blob from Storage Accounts to my virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Azure Storage Python SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python) for that. You can use this examples file as a base and official docs:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/samples/blob/block_blob_usage.py#L329
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python

```
full_path_to_file2 = os.path.join(local_path, string.replace(local_file_name ,'.txt', '_DOWNLOADED.txt'))
print("\nDownloading blob to " + full_path_to_file2)
block_blob_service.get_blob_to_path(container_name, local_file_name, full_path_to_file2)
```

Comment: Thank you for all your time,from the above code snippet it seems that the file should get copy from azure storage to local folder. but i need to copy blob from azure storage to Azure VM.how can i achieve that ?

Comment: well, you need to run this on the vm, there is no api to put things directly inside the vm, but there is an api to run custom script inside the vm. you could create\test a script that works locally and invoke it inside the vm. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linuxostc

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use Azure Function with Blob Storage Trigger to copy blobs from Azure Storage to Linux Virtual Machine using Python.

So a feasible solution is to use some Python packages [`scp`](https://pypi.org/project/scp/) or [`ssh2-python`](https://pypi.org/project/ssh2-python/) with Azure Storage Python SDK together on Azure Function to realize the feature which can download blobs and transfer to Linux VM via these Python packages like linux command `scp`.

As I known, there is a virtual file system adapter for Azure Blob storage on Linux [`azure-storage-fuse`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-fuse), which can mount a Blob container with `blobfuse` to Linux local filesystem as a directory. Per my experience, the other workaround way is to mount a specified Blob Container which you uploaded files to your Linux VM, then you can directly access these files like on local. Azure Function with Blob Trigger just need to notify the event of new upload file to your related application on your Linux VM.