# How to copy the blob from the Azure storage to linux virtual machine using Java?

Tags: java, linux, azure, azure-functions, azure-cloud-services

I am new to Azure cloud services. I want to copy files from the Azure blob storage to the Linux Machine using Java.
I am trying to do it using a function app.
I have tried searching various places but not able to find suitable answer.
Is there any link or sample code snippet do it, That would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found a similar solution but it is in python. If anyone can help convert it in java?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54387868/how-to-copy-the-blob-from-the-azure-storage-to-linux-virtual-machine-using-pytho

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob): you may find the *Download a blob to local path* section useful

Comment: how about azcopy util? You can install it to your target machine. Then you'll be able to trigger it from outside (e.g ssh connect from cloud function to machine and call azcopy) or you can write some tiny app, that exposes single http endpoint and calls azcopy under the hood

Comment: also take a look here, this is official java client for blob storage https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java?tabs=powershell%2Cenvironment-variable-windows

Comment: Here is an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/azure-sdk-for-java-storage-blob-upload-download/upload-download-blobs-java/